# Changing the background color of a dropdown list after an option is chosen in HTML

Tags: html

I have a cloze (or fill in the gaps). I placed a drop down list in every gap, and the user should choose the right word (option) to fill the gap. If the wrong word (option) is chosen, the background color should become red, if the right word is chosen, the background color should become green. Is there any help? If easier, it will do if the forecolor of the chosen word changes.

Comment: Could you provide example code?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<select data-correctVal="yes">
    <option val="yes">Yes</option>
    <option val="no">No</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).attr("background-color", ($(this).attr("data-correctVal") == $(this).val()) ? "green" : "red");
});
```

Here's a [working example on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/2pt33af1/2/).

Comment: Thanks very much indeed, Jonathan! The Code in jQuery is exactly what I mean ... unfortunately the color part in HTML is missing :-( I wrote in HTML only

Comment: @Matt Surely there's a way to incorporate some JS in your code? AFAIK, dynamic styles (and scripting in general) are only available with a scripting language such as JS (client-side) or PHP (server-side)...

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, I will try to incorporate it. Now it's 05:30 in Germany, I worked the whole night through (on something different) ... I hope I can present you a result ... tomorrow! So long!